# how we can solve double free corruption

Tags: c

I have two pointer have same address. If I free one. I should not use 2nd one. because its free memory But I might be using that in next code. Also if I free one I cant free second .Plz give me solution with example.

Comment: Use a **shared pointer**.

Comment: Don't free it twice, and only free it when you're done with the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that when you free one of the two pointers, then set both to NULL.  Also, it is a good programming practice to always test that a pointer is set before using it.

```
 char *ptr1 = malloc(80);

 char *ptr2 = ptr1;

 free(ptr2);
 ptr1 = ptr2 = NULL;
 // other stuff happens here, and if the code doesn't "know"
 // that ptr1 is set correctly then...
 if (ptr1 != NULL)
 {  // etc.

 }
```

Hope this is what you were asking, and hope it helps.  Good Luck with your future coding endeavors.

Comment: Good programming practice?! Tests like “if (ptr1 != NULL)” fill your code with content-free boilerplate that's irrelevant to the intention of the program. If you are going to check each pointer before using it, use a memory-safe programming language, it will be more efficient (the compiler will only insert checks it knows to be necessary based on higher-level invariants) and the source code will be more readable.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, if using c you should check the pointers.  I will edit my answer to be a little more realistic.